# Android : Different type of Json content parsing using Gson

Tags: android, gson

I am starting to use Gson to parse json data.

Jason content will be like

```
{ 
  “type”: “type1”, 
  “date”: “Tue, 16 May 2017 07:09:33 +0000”, 
  “body”: 
  { 
     “formatA_1”: “aaa”, 
     “formatA_2”: “bbbcccddd” 
  } 
}
```

or

```
{ 
 “type”: “type_2”, 
 “date”: “Tue, 16 May 2017 07:09:33 +0000”, 
 “body”: 
 { 
    “formatB_1”: “alpha” 
 } 
}
```

There will be different kind of types currently to 8 different types. The major different is the "body" part.

The "body" part can have different format and different content even the arraylist or null is possible.

So i design the data class be

```
public class Data {

    private String type;

    private Long date;

    private String body;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public long getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
}
```

First i thought that depends on the type, later i can parse the body string, but got the exception:

```
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 10 path $.body
```

Is this the only way that i modify the Data class with nested body class?

public class Data {

```
    private String type;

    private Long date;

    private Body body;

 private class Body {
    private String formatA_1;

    private String formatA_2;

    private String formatB_1;

    //even for the list and other data members...
 }
```

}

This design is a bit mess because it contains all the members of the different "type" (type1 , type2, type3, ...). 
I want to be that based on different "type", i can parse body to different object (POJO for body). Is that possible?

I am just start to study for using Gson and don't know how to make a better design and parse.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's *JSON* (not *Jason*).

Comment: Thanks a lot. typo error.

Answer (score 0):

In Question you asking to avoid nested objects , there is only two ways to deal with this and that is to parse data manually , or use **@Expose** tag in **POJO**  otherwise you have to create a complete POJO as it is.

By Though way i recommend using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for auto parsing of GSON POJO's from json.

For Detailed parsing examples and there is a good read at http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2

Comment: Can you help a bit explain about use @Expose tag in POJO? I don't understand what does it mean. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this tag allows to disable the serialization or deserialization of json POJO , for more detail check the links in answer or [read this](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can define your `class Body` as a generic class.

```
private String type;
private Long date;
private List<T> body;
```

you have to read more about how to parse a generic class.